# How to list all files, folders, subfolders and subfiles of a Google drive folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-drive-api

Any ideas how to query for all the children and the children of the children in a single query?

**Update**

It seems like a simple question. I doubt if there is a simple solution?

Quering the tree of folders and files can cost a lot of API calls.
So, to solve my problem, I use a single query to list all the files and folders of an owner. This query also returns subfiles and subfolders. To find the folder and all of its children (folder, files, subfolders and subfiles) in the list, I had to create a tree like index.

**Conclusion**

A single query is not enough. You have to list all or narrow the query with an owner. Next You have to index the results to (recursive) find the tree for the folder.

A query option like (ls -R in Unix) would be nice.

Comment: What did you try? Did you check https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list ?

Comment: A lot. But I was not able to solve it in a single query. Using a list query with an owner give me to much results, also from other folders.

Comment: That page includes an explicit example.

Comment: I need the children and the children of the children from a specific drive folder. Or do I overlook something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the right idea in your "update". Treat Drive as flat, make calls to list everything, and generate your own tree from that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to do the same in PHP. My solution is:

1. Retrieve the complete list of files and folders from the drive
2. Make a double iteration (nested) on the retrieved json:

   - the first over the elements in "items" array,
   - the second (recursive) over the parents id of each element,

rejecting all the elements that not contain the id of my specific folder in its parents id list.
Don't worry, it's just one Google APIs call. The rest of the job is local.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I use the same method in Python.