# Accessing folders, subfolders and subfiles using PyDrive (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, metadata, google-api-python-client

I have the following code from the PyDrive documentation that allows access to top level folders in my Google Drive. I would like to access all of the folders, subfolders, and files from it. How would I go about doing this (I just started using PyDrive)?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive


gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth() # Creates local webserver and auto handles authentication

#Make GoogleDrive instance with Authenticated GoogleAuth instance
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

#Google_Drive_Tree = 
# Auto-iterate through all files that matches this query
top_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
for file in top_list:
    print 'title: %s, id: %s' % (file['title'], file['id'])
    print "---------------------------------------------"

#Paginate file lists by specifying number of max results
for file_list in drive.ListFile({'q': 'trashed=true', 'maxResults': 10}):
    print 'Received %s files from Files.list()' % len(file_list) # <= 10
    for file1 in file_list:
        print 'title: %s, id: %s' % (file1['title'], file1['id'])
```

I have checked the following page [How to list all files, folders, subfolders and subfiles of a Google drive folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753914/how-to-list-all-files-folders-subfolders-and-subfiles-of-a-google-drive-folder) , which seemed to be the answer I was looking for but the code is not there anymore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is absolutely correct. But with the default settings of Pydrive , you have access to only the root level files and folders. 
Changing oauth_scope in settings.yaml file fixes this issue.

```
client_config_backend: settings
client_config:
client_id: XXX
client_secret: XXXX

save_credentials: True
save_credentials_backend: file
save_credentials_file: credentials.json

get_refresh_token: True

oauth_scope:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata
```

Comment: After I changed `oauth_scope` I had to delete `credentials.json`, create an empty new `credentials.json` file and authenticate again for the app to get access to the new scopes.

Answer (score 10):

It requires iteration with list of files. Based on [this](https://github.com/googledrive/PyDrive/issues/37), the code fetches the title of file and url link of the each files with in the folder. The code is adjustable to get the specific folder by supplying the `id` of the folder such as `ListFolder('id')`. The given below example is querying the `root`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth() # Creates local webserver and auto handles authentication

#Make GoogleDrive instance with Authenticated GoogleAuth instance
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

def ListFolder(parent):
  filelist=[]
  file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'%s' in parents and trashed=false" % parent}).GetList()
  for f in file_list:
    if f['mimeType']=='application/vnd.google-apps.folder': # if folder
        filelist.append({"id":f['id'],"title":f['title'],"list":ListFolder(f['id'])})
    else:
        filelist.append({"title":f['title'],"title1":f['alternateLink']})
  return filelist

ListFolder('root')
```

Comment: Maybe need some rate limiting in this though also

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on getting all the files within the subfolders...
This lets you query by the path you set. This is different because it doesn't make 1 request for each folder. It creates batches of folders to query.

Batch Snippet:

```
'some_id_1234' in parents or 'some_id_1235' in parents or 'some_id_1236' in parents or 'some_id_1237' in parents or 'some_id_1238' in parents or 'some_id_1239' in parents or 'some_id_1240' in parents and trashed=false
```

You can then query the files in more than 1 folder at a time. Your query can't be too large in size, so anything over 300+ folders (*'some_id_1234' in parents'*), you will start to get errors, so keep the batch size around 250.

Say the folder you want to check has 1,110 folders and you set your batch size to 250.
It will then make 5 separate requests to query all the folders.

-Request 1 queries 250 folders

-Request 2 queries 250 folders

-Request 3 queries 250 folders

-Request 4 queries 250 folders

-Request 5 queries 110 folders

Then any subfolders inside there will be created into batches and queried recursively.

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive



def parse_gdrive_path(gd_path):
    if ':' in gd_path:
        gd_path = gd_path.split(':')[1]
    gd_path = gd_path.replace('\\', '/').replace('//', '/')
    if gd_path.startswith('/'):
        gd_path = gd_path[1:]
    if gd_path.endswith('/'):
        gd_path = gd_path[:-1]
    return gd_path.split('/')


def resolve_path_to_id(folder_path):
    _id = 'root'
    folder_path = parse_gdrive_path(folder_path)
    for idx, folder in enumerate(folder_path):
        folder_list = gdrive.ListFile({'q': f"'{_id}' in parents and title='{folder}' and trashed=false and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'", 'fields': 'items(id, title, mimeType)'}).GetList()
        _id = folder_list[0]['id']
        title = folder_list[0]['title']
        if idx == (len(folder_path) - 1) and folder == title:
            return _id
    return _id


def get_folder_files(folder_ids, batch_size=100):

    base_query = "'{target_id}' in parents"
    target_queries = []
    query = ''

    for idx, folder_id in enumerate(folder_ids):
        query += base_query.format(target_id=folder_id)
        if len(folder_ids) == 1 or idx > 0 and idx % batch_size == 0:
            target_queries.append(query)
            query = ''
        elif idx != len(folder_ids)-1:
            query += " or "
        else:
            target_queries.append(query)

    for query in target_queries:
        for f in gdrive.ListFile({'q': f"{query} and trashed=false", 'fields': 'items(id, title, mimeType, version)'}).GetList():
            yield f


def get_files(folder_path=None, target_ids=None, files=[]):

    if target_ids is None:
        target_ids = [resolve_path_to_id(folder_path)]

    file_list = get_folder_files(folder_ids=target_ids, batch_size=250)

    subfolder_ids = []

    for f in file_list:
        if f['mimeType'] == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder':
            subfolder_ids.append(f['id'])
        else:
            files.append(f['title'])

    if len(subfolder_ids) > 0:
        get_files(target_ids=subfolder_ids)

    return files


gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

gdrive = GoogleDrive(gauth)


file_list = get_files('/Some/Folder/Path')

for f in file_list:
    print(f)
```

So for example:

Your google drive contains this:

```
(folder) Root
    (folder) Docs
        (subfolder) Notes
            (subfolder) School
                (file) notes_1.txt
                (file) notes_2.txt
                (file) notes_3.txt
                (file) notes_4.txt
                (file) notes_5.txt
                (subfolder) Important
                    (file) important_notes_1.txt
                    (file) important_notes_2.txt
                    (file) important_notes_3.txt
                (subfolder) Old Notes
                    (file) old_1.txt
                    (file) old_2.txt
                    (file) old_3.txt
                    (subfolder) Secrets
                        (file) secret_1.txt
                        (file) secret_2.txt
                        (file) secret_3.txt
    (folder) Stuff
        (file) nothing.txt
        (file) this-will-not-be-found.txt
```

And you want to get all the files from the "Notes" folder/subfolders

You would do:

```
file_list = get_files('/Docs/Notes')

for f in file_list:
    print(f)
```

```
Output:

>> notes_1.txt
>> notes_2.txt
>> notes_3.txt
>> notes_4.txt
>> notes_5.txt
>> important_notes_1.txt
>> important_notes_2.txt
>> important_notes_3.txt
>> old_1.txt
>> old_2.txt
>> old_3.txt
>> secret_1.txt
>> secret_2.txt
>> secret_3.txt
```

Hopefully this helps someone :)