# Invalid Query, Drive api, files.list()

Tags: python, google-drive-api, drive, pydrive

this functions:

```
drive.ListFile({'q': " id = '"+Value+"' and trashed=false"}).GetList()
```

return: "Invalid query"

The problem lies in the selector 'id', if I raise this condition I return a dictionary with the parameter 'id'

I am used this doc, 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list
and
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters

It works perfectly for other selectors, but for 'id' should not be

Comment: What do you mean with "[...] but for 'id' it should not be"? It should not be what?

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: Here is how you can access metadata, and get and set content of an existing file by its ID.

```
# Calling CreateFile() with an existing ID links it to the already existing file.
gdrive_file = drive.CreateFile({'id': '<your file id>'})
gdrive_file.FetchMetadata() # Only needed if you want to view or edit its metadata.
# Do things with metadata here as needed.

gdrive_file.GetContentFile('dog.png') # Download content file.

# And/or upload a new content file.
gdrive_file.SetContentFile('cat.png') 
gdrive_file.Upload()
```

And, of course, the [docs](https://googledrive.github.io/PyDrive/docs/build/html/filemanagement.html#upload-and-update-file-content) have a bunch of examples.

**Original**:
Have a look at the [docs for file listings](https://googledrive.github.io/PyDrive/docs/build/html/filelist.html) for examples.

Make sure that you

1. Don't introduce your own spaces surrounding `=` signs,
2. PyDrive uses the Google Drive API v2, so make sure you use [the v2 search parameter page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters) instead,
3. The ID is the folder ID assigned by Google Drive, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224559/list-of-file-in-a-folder-drive-api-pydrive/40236586#40236586) lists ways to find the ID.

For example:

```py
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth) # Create GoogleDrive instance with authenticated GoogleAuth instance
folder_id = "insert your folder ID here"

# Auto-iterate through all files in the specified folder.
file_list = drive.ListFile({
    'q': "{id} in parents and trashed=false".format(id=folder_id)
}).GetList()

for file1 in file_list:
  print('title: %s, id: %s' % (file1['title'], file1['id']))
```

Answer (score 1):

`id` is not a supported query field for doing file search.

Check the documentation [for Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters) to see valid fields to search by.