# How to find the sub folder id in Google Drive using pydrive in Python?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

The directory stricture on Google Drive is as follows:
Inside mydrive/BTP/BTP-4

I need to get the folder ID for BTP-4 so that I can transfer a specific file from the folder. How do I do it?

```
fileList = GoogleDrive(self.driveConn).ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
for file in fileList:
    if (file['title'] == "BTP-4"):
        fileID = file['id']
        print(remoteFile, fileID)
        return fileID
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34101427/accessing-folders-subfolders-and-subfiles-using-pydrive-python this can help you.

Comment: It actually did but say I have the path of the file i need to download. Will be able to give path like /MyDrive/BTP/BTP-4 and filename as "test.csv" and then directly download the file?

Comment: Add your code which you tried other than this

Comment: for i, file1 in enumerate(sorted(file_list, key=lambda x: x['title']), start=1):
                if "." in file1['title']:
                    try:
                        print('Downloading {} from GDrive ({}/{})'.format(file1['title'], i, len(file_list)))
                        file1.GetContentFile(os.path.join("C:\\Desktop", file1['title']))
                    except Exception as e:
                        print("UNABLE TO TRANSFER FILES:" + str(e))

Comment: Update in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will be able to give path like /MyDrive/BTP/BTP-4 and filename as "test.csv" and then directly download the file?

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, this is not possible.*

#### More Information:

Google Drive supports creating multiple files or folders with the same name in the same location:

[image]

As a result of this, in some cases, providing a file path isn't enough to identify a file or folder uniquiely - in this case `mydrive/Parent folder/Child folder/Child doc` points to two different files, and `mydrive/Parent folder/Child folder/Child folder` points to five different folders.

You have to either directly search for the folder with its ID, or to get a folder/file's ID you have to search for children recursively through the folders like you are already doing.