# Read files in Python using PyDrive

Tags: python-3.x, pydrive

I am trying to read files (specifically ,txt, .py, and .nii.gz type files) in Python using PyDrive. So far, I am able to get a list of file names and file ids (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47764444) but not sure how to proceed reading the files in Google Drive.

Comment: I guess you have to [download the file](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html#download-file-content) first?

Comment: Is there no way to read files without downloading?

Comment: There isn't a way.