# List All Folder and Files from FolderID

Tags: google-drive-api

If I now want to read all files and folders from a specific folder (FolderID), I use this:

success = rest.AddQueryParam("q", "'" & strParentID & "' in parents")

The problem is that I only get all the folders and files that are directly in that folder.
What do I have to change so that I also get the subfolders and subsubfolders with all files?

Read doku.
if found nothing

Comment: Here is something that might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753914/how-to-list-all-files-folders-subfolders-and-subfiles-of-a-google-drive-folder?rq=2